# How will the Client know the Structure of the class when doing a Rest call in JaxRs and Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Comment Class with the following parameters

```
package com.rahul.restapi.messenger.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//added to test json response
@XmlRootElement
public class Comment {


    private long id;
    private String message;
    private Date created;
    private String author;

    public Comment() {

    }

    public Comment(long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }



}
```

and using the Rest Client By JaxRS i call the below URL

http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/date/yesterday/messageJson

How will the client get get to know the Implementation of Comment Class so as to get the Response Properly in json format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The progress bar also has an indeterminant by setting the value to -1.  This will have the progress bar just animate until the process is finished when you set it back to 0.  If your progress can't be incrementally determined like the snippet above, this provides indication to the user that the system is busy.

Comment: Can you please tell how to achieve that  its will be of great help

Comment: Just update the progress of the task based on the calculation of i + 1 / N_ITERATIONS, The value is bound to the ProgressBar's progress property so it will update accordingly. That code would be found in the updateProgress method which you haven't shown us here. If your code does not involve iterations, then simply update progress based on some other factor of the task. If there's no progress factor to your task, then there's no point binding it to a progress bar at all.

Comment: But here again its a lot of manual work right, any other possibility as@ purring pigeon said i i donot know how to implement that

Comment: @purring pigeon i got what you are trying to say and i have already implemented that but is there a way to actually update it .

Comment: If you don't want to use a `Task` you can use `SimpleDoubleProperty` to track the progress (0.0 to 1.0) and `bind()` it to the `ProgressBar`. When you update your `SimpleDoubleProperty` object, the `ProgressBar` will be updated. This is essentially what happens when you use `Task` as well, it just uses the Observer pattern.

Comment: @d.j.brown But then you would have to take care of 1. making sure you set the property on the FX Application Thread (since changing its value would cause a change in the UI via the binding) and 2. making sure you didn't flood the FX Application Thread with too many updates, by throttling those calls if necessary. The `updateProgress(...)` method takes care of all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following.

```
   public <T> void someLongRunningMethod() {
         Service<T> service = //Code here to create your service or task
         service.addEventFilter(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, event -> toggleProgressIndicator(pi, false));
         service.addEventFilter(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_FAILED, event -> toggleProgressIndicator(pi, false));
         service.addEventFilter(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_CANCELLED, event -> toggleProgressIndicator(pi, false));
         service.addEventFilter(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_RUNNING, event -> toggleProgressIndicator(pi, true));
         service.start();
    }

private void toggleProgressIndicator(ProgressIndicator pi, boolean start) {
    if(start){
        pi.toFront();
        pi.setVisible(true);
        pi.progressProperty().set(-1);
    }else {
        pi.toBack();
        pi.setVisible(false);
        pi.progressProperty().set(0);
    }
}
```